# Which Android SDK Api compatible with Android NDK r10e?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a android jni that compiled with android-ndk-r10e.
I'm going to use in android sdk.
I want to know the minimum android sdk version that can use this jni.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ndk-r10** introduced **APP_PLATFORM=android-21**, which has some major incompatibilities with older platforms. But the JNI library could have been compiled with any **APP_PLATFORM**, starting from **android-3**. You can try to load the library on emulator, and find the version that breaks.

Comment: So your words mean, I can use my android jni on android api version 17 without any problem. right?

Comment: Try to load the library on a Jelly Bean MR2 device or emulator. If it loads, you can use it.

Comment: I just make a simple test android project.
I load my so file like this.

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("example.so");
    }
    ....
}
but it occurs an error on my phone. then I can't use it. right?

Comment: maybe the problem is simply that `loadLibrary()` does not expect `.so` suffix?

Comment: Thanks. it works. I have a mistake in library name. I used "libexample" instead of "example".